# Moving Graph Titles in the Y axis of Subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

This question is adapted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191519/python-matplotlib-moving-graph-title-to-the-y-axis), however the solution provided does not work and following is my result. I am interested in adding individual title on the right side for individual subgraphs.

(p.s no matter how much offset for y-axis i provide the title seems to stay at the same y-value)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax0label = axes[0].set_ylabel('Axes 0')
ax1label = axes[1].set_ylabel('Axes 1')

title = axes[0].set_title('Title')

offset = np.array([-0.15, 0.0])
title.set_position(ax0label.get_position() + offset)
title.set_rotation(90)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? This is the only other way i can think of.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax0label = axes[0].set_ylabel('Axes 0')
ax1label = axes[1].set_ylabel('Axes 1')
ax01 = axes[0].twinx()
ax02 = axes[1].twinx()
ax01.set_ylabel('title')
ax02.set_ylabel('title')


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: right labels]

Comment: close, i want the Title to be centered to each plot in the right, just like Axis 0 and Axis 1 are centered to each plot on the left

Comment: I updated it. Requires twinx() though.

Comment: ok, I accepted the answer. Is there a way to remove/suppress the 2nd axis and keep the title?

Comment: ok I got it! all I have to do now is this `ax01.set_yticks([])` & `ax02.set_yticks([])`.

Comment: Yeah exactly, a few ways to manipulate it, but soundslike you got it!